# Integrate $\frac{a^2}{a^2+\cos^2(x)}$

Tags: definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{a^2}{a^2+\cos^2(x)}\mathrm{d}x$$

The question is really definite integral from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. I've tried Wolfram on the indefinite integral: it gives complicated expression.

Is there some trick to calculating definite and if not indefinite then?

Comment: this kind of questions was asked (and answered) 100's of times before.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide all terms by $cos^2x$ and use $sec^2x=tan^2x+1$ to replace the $sec^2x$ in the denominator. Finally u-sub $tanx=t$ You then need to integrate $\frac{a^2dt}{a^2+1+a^2t^2}$ from $t=0$ to $t=inf$  Can you do that? (You will end up with an arctan)

Comment: yup- I think I see how to finish this- something with arctan

Comment: Your integration limits after substitution are incorrect. $\tan{x}$ goes to $+\infty$.

Comment: @DavidH. Yep thanks, I was thinking about $tan{\frac{x}{2}}=t$ from the tangent half angle sub, which was also going through my mind as an alternative method...

Comment: @imranfat Figured =). Downvote removed.